# Spark SQL WHERE EXISTS conditional clause

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I am trying to write a Spark SQL job to populate a table that will not exist on the job’s first run. The table appends the delta between preceding table and it.

So..

```
Select 
*
From
preceeding_table
Where
dt > (Select max(dt) from current_table) and 
EXISTS (Select * from information_schema.tables where table=‘current_table’)
```

If my current_table does not exist, just select * from preceeding_table.

Anyone know how to make the where clause conditional so that no filter is applied if table does not exist without running a separate SQL query?

Comment: I don't know *Spark* but I would imagine it's no different from any other RDBMS in this regard, you will need to check if the table exists by using either the *information_schema* or bespoke system views.

Comment: Thanks Stu. Updated my post. Aware of information schema - not sure how to make the whereclause conditional on its existence

Comment: I wouldn't think you can; a SQL query is compiled and an execution plan produced and potentially cached, it cannot dynamically change at runtime, afaik you will need to check if it exists and dynamically execute the correct statement.

Comment: You'll need yo use scala/python api, you can't do this using only SQL: `if spark.catalog.tableExists("current_table"): spark.sql("...") else spark.sql("...")`

Comment: What about adding a `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` at the beginning and writing the query to handle an empty table? This way you can assume it always exists